Changing TabView background colouring is inconsistent accross navigation
I have a TabView and a header that are persistant accross all views.
The issue have come up against is that the background of the TabView bar is not consistent when the user navigates through the app. Occasionally it goes transparent.
I believe this is due to how the TabView is displayed when there is a scrolled edge but I can't implement the fix.
Below is a code snippet to understand the layout of the appx
struct MainView: View {

   

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            HeaderView(viewModel: viewModel)
                    TabView (){
                           NavigationStack {
                               ListOfActs(viewModel: viewModel)
                                    .navigationBarHidden(true)
                           }
                           .background(Color.colorPrimaryDark)
                           .tabItem {
                                Label("Library", systemImage: "book")
                            }

                            
                            NavigationStack {
                                CollectionFrontPage(viewModel: viewModel)
                                    .navigationBarHidden(true)
                            }
                            .tabItem {
                                Label("Collections", systemImage: "ellipsis.curlybraces")
                            }
                            
                            NavigationStack {
                                Search(viewModel: viewModel)
                            }
                            .tabItem {
                                Label("Search", systemImage: "magnifyingglass")
                            }
                            
                            NavigationStack {
                                InfoFrontPage(viewModel: viewModel)
                                    .navigationBarHidden(true)
                            }
                            
                            .tabItem {
                                Label("Info", systemImage: "info.circle")
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                
                    .toolbar(.visible, for: .tabBar)
                    .toolbarBackground(Color.colorPrimaryDark, for: .tabBar)
                    .accentColor(.white)
                    .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
}

These lines work fine on this first opening page
                    .toolbar(.visible, for: .tabBar)
                    .toolbarBackground(Color.colorPrimaryDark, for: .tabBar)

Of the tabs, 3 of them keep the colour of the TabView, but not Search. There are other screens in the app that are further down the navigation stack that also don't work, but if I get it working for Search I'm sure it will work elsewhere.
Below is a simplified version of my Search file
struct Search: View {
    @State private var searchText = ""
    
    var body: some View {

        var searchResultDictionary: [(key: String, value: [Data])] {
            //Builds an array of tuples for search results on detecting searchText changing
        }
        
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
              
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVStack(pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders]) {
                       
                        ForEach(searchResultDictionary, id: \.key) { act, dataGroup in
                            Section(header: SectionHeaderView(stringToDisplay: act) {
                                ForEach(dataGroup, id: \.uniqueID) { entry in
                                    NavigationLink(destination: DataView(uniqueID: entry.uniqueID) {
                                        DataViewInList(data: entry)
                                            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                                            .padding(.vertical, 5)
                                            .padding(.horizontal)
                                    }
                                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                                }
                                .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                .searchable(text: $searchText, placement: .automatic)
      
            }
        }
        .toolbar(.visible, for: .tabBar)
        .toolbarBackground(Color.colorPrimaryDark, for: .tabBar)

    }
}


I have tried using the lines
        .toolbar(.visible, for: .tabBar)
        .toolbarBackground(Color.colorPrimaryDark, for: .tabBar)

On any of the views navigated to with no luck.
I have also tried adding the following to the @main entry point of the app:
    init() {
        // Configure the tab bar appearance globally
        let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor(Color.colorPrimaryDark)

        // Customize tab bar items appearance if needed
        appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.iconColor = UIColor.white
        appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.iconColor = UIColor.gray
        appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.gray]

        // Apply the appearance to the tab bar globally
        UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
        UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    }

This hasn't worked either.
The issue is definitely linked to the content in the main view. For example, the Search screen when first loaded has a transparant TabView, but if you search and the screen is filled with results (interacting with the TabView) then the bar reverts to colorPrimaryDark.
Any help would be appreciated!

This needs a [mre]

Note, you don't need yet another NavigationStack in your Search view, the one in the TabView is enough. Also, you should not declare var searchResultDictionary: ... inside the body of a view, move it outside, in .onAppear for example.

For anyone who ended up here looking for the answer.
Turns out that using
        .toolbar(.visible, for: .tabBar)
        .toolbarBackground(Color.colorPrimaryDark, for: .tabBar)

And the UITabBar modifiers together was the issue. Removing all the toolbar modifiers for all views resolved the issue.
